High Voltage Switching using OPTO MOSFET
I have made a circuit using OPTO MOSFET for turning electro magnet ON/Off.
The issue is when opto MOSFET turns on the current limiting resistor 2.7 kΩ heats up. It's a 2 W resistor. Opto MOSFET is KAQw214 and its turned on and off using PWM. In working condition I have tested electro magnet and it draws 140 mA current in older circuit.


What's the resistance of your electromagnet coil?

KAQW214 cannot switch 140 mA load current. Was this the reason to insert the resistor?


I have tested electro magnet and it draws 140 mA current in older circuit.

Assuming this is the current draw for the same supply voltage (300 VDC) and without any current limiting resistor, the resistance of the coil can be approximated to 2k2.
So if a 300 VDC source is loaded with a total resistance of ~5k then the total dissipation will be 18W which makes the dissipation across the 2k7 about 10W. You can multiply this by the duty cycle to get the average dissipation. For your 2-W rated (at what conditions?) resistor, even for a duty cycle of ~10-15% it's looks normal to get a burning resistor.

Well Rohat,
Thanks for the info. Is there any other method to drive this magnet ON and OFF ?
